# Python pandas.date_range shows wrong starttime value

Tags: datetime, pandas

I want to use pandas.date_range function as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
start_date = '2013-01-01'
end_date = '2014-03-01'
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='M')
```

When I print dates, the first value in the range is '2013-01-31' instead of my defined `start_date`, while the last value jumps to the end of the month of the value defined by `end_date`. This happens with every kind of date I define.

```
print dates
# output:
#<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
#[2013-01-31 00:00:00, ..., 2014-03-31 00:00:00]
#Length: 15, Freq: M, Timezone: None
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `freq='M'` indicates that the date range will use dates which are the ends of months. To use dates which are the start of months, use `freq='MS'`. There is a list of the available aliases and their meanings, [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).

```
>>> pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS')    
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-01, ..., 2014-03-01]
Length: 15, Freq: MS, Timezone: None
```